# Reading in memory db file with sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I would like to process db file in memory using sqlite. Actually I read the db file from a Azure Storage Account using this block of code to stream:

```
string connstr = @"connstring";
CloudStorageAccount storageaccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connstr);
CloudBlobClient blobclient = storageaccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobclient.GetContainerReference("sample");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("dbfile");
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
```

Now I have this expectation that the db file is in memory and I can read the tables in this db files using this block of code:

```
 SQLiteConnection mc = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=:memory:");
 mc.Open();
 string Tables = @"select name from sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';"; 
 //more Code
```

but it seems that this code can not find the streem in memory to open a connection with it. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I don’t see anyrhing related to reading from the stream, but I suspect what might be the problem. Try setting the position to 0 before reading from the stream. `memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`

Comment: I the second c# block you can see that I have set the Data source like this: `Data Source=:memory:`. according to sqlite documentation this enables sqlite to read from memory. I have tested your line of code, but still doesnt work!

Comment: Alright, I got that, try it with this connection string to see it has any difference `FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared;` Last try

Comment: As you described I have changed my connection string to `SQLiteConnection mc = new SQLiteConnection(@"FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared;");` but nothing changed! :/

Comment: I just had a look at the documentation and I think we both got this wrong. Sqlite supports having an in-memory database but not loading ita content from a memory stream. As you don’t give it any pointer to the stream you have just created, how should it know what to load? On the other hand, you can open a sqlconnection to an existing sqlite stored in a file and copy (backup) its content to an in-memory instance and then solely use that one for other operations.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. then it is not possible to load a file to memory and then open it via sqlite in memory, as I understood. Do you have may be any idea, how can I solve it?

Comment: Sqlite is more a local standalone databass. You should probably consider using some other solution, or if you must use this one the only approach I see is saving the data from the blobstorage to a file on the local drive and then loading the sqlconnection from there.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of this implementation? Do you need SQL for what you’re doing? If the answer is yes, why don’t you use AzureTables and then have all the sql stuff in the cloud, if the answer is no, then why not use some other format for the data - csv / or multiple blobs identified by some business criteria.

Comment: If you have a byte-by-byte exact in memory version of the contents of a database file you can use [sqlite3_deserialize()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html) to get a handle to it, but it's easier to write it to a file and open that. Plus I don't know if the c sharp bindings provide the serialization API...

Comment: @Mihai thank you so much for your answer. Actually, I have no impact on the format of this file. These files with this format are saved in blob and I should convert them in CSV. Because I have many of this file and most of them 
 are relative big files I thought, that I do the CSV convert of these files in memory, but unfortunately it does not possible :/